# Tensorflow image processing: how to predict mask

Tags: tensorflow

I am very much a beginner and currently trying to get started with CNNs. I wanted to try out lane detection.
Using the tusimple dataset, I have images of roads and create masks with the lanes. It looks like this:
[image]

I was following [this](https://programmathically.com/deep-learning-for-semantic-image-segmentation-a-worked-example-in-tensorflow/) blog where something similar is done. However, my results look nothing like in the blog. For simplicity reasons, I only use one image as dataset. This way, the network should very easily be able to detect the lane in this one image. However, this cnn basically just adds a red filter on the input image. The output looks somewhat like this: [image]

Maybe you can point me into the right direction / tell me what I am doing wrong.
I posted the whole notebook here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1igOulIU-1HA-Ecf4diQTLXM-mrnAeFXz?usp=sharing

Or the most relevant code included:

```
def convolutional_block(inputs=None, n_filters=32, dropout_prob=0, max_pooling=True):
    
    conv = Conv2D(n_filters, 
                  kernel_size = 3,     
                  activation='relu',
                  padding='same',
                  kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal())(inputs)
    conv = Conv2D(n_filters, 
                  kernel_size = 3, 
                  activation='relu',
                  padding='same',
                  kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal())(conv)
   
    
    if dropout_prob > 0:
        conv = Dropout(dropout_prob)(conv)
        
    if max_pooling:
        next_layer = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(conv)
        
        
    else:
        next_layer = conv
        
    #conv = BatchNormalization()(conv)
    skip_connection = conv
    
    return next_layer, skip_connection

def upsampling_block(expansive_input, contractive_input, n_filters=32):
    
    up = Conv2DTranspose(
                 n_filters,  
                 kernel_size = 3,
                 strides=(2,2),
                 padding='same')(expansive_input)
    
    merge = concatenate([up, contractive_input], axis=3)
    conv = Conv2D(n_filters,  
                 kernel_size = 3,   
                 activation='relu',
                 padding='same',
                 kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal())(merge)
    conv = Conv2D(n_filters,  
                 kernel_size = 3,  
                 activation='relu',
                 padding='same',
                 kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal())(conv)

    return conv

def unet_model(input_size=(720, 1280,3), n_filters=32, n_classes=3):

    inputs = Input(input_size)

    #contracting path
    cblock1 = convolutional_block(inputs, n_filters)
    cblock2 = convolutional_block(cblock1[0], 2*n_filters)
    cblock3 = convolutional_block(cblock2[0], 4*n_filters)
    cblock4 = convolutional_block(cblock3[0], 8*n_filters, dropout_prob=0.2) 
    cblock5 = convolutional_block(cblock4[0],16*n_filters, dropout_prob=0.2, max_pooling=None)     

    #expanding path
    ublock6 = upsampling_block(cblock5[0], cblock4[1],  8 * n_filters)
    ublock7 = upsampling_block(ublock6, cblock3[1],  n_filters*4)
    ublock8 = upsampling_block(ublock7,cblock2[1] , n_filters*2)
    ublock9 = upsampling_block(ublock8,cblock1[1],  n_filters)
    conv9 = Conv2D(n_classes,
             1,
             activation='relu',
             padding='same',
             kernel_initializer='he_normal')(ublock9)

    conv10 = Activation('softmax')(conv9)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=conv10)
    return model
```

Comment: maybe work checking the paper about UNet https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597

Comment: Hi @tailoxyn, could you please refer to this [document](https://github.com/MaybeShewill-CV/lanenet-lane-detection) may help to resolve your issue. Thank You.